# Freeradius with eap_sim module

Tags: freeradius

I am having trouble installing FreeRADIUS with EAP-SIM support. I installed the latest FreeRADIUS 3.2.1, using the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server.git
cd freeradius-server
git checkout v3.2.x
./configure --disable-shared
make
make install
```

After installation I did not see any `eap_sim` module under `/usr/local/etc/raddb/mods-available`, I only see the `eap` module.

Are there any extra steps in the installation to get this module available?

-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`rlm_eap_sim` builds on a standard system and has little in the way of dependencies. You will need to read the output from `configure` to see why it did not build.

(I do not believe that `--disable-shared` does anything these days. All the modules are shared libraries.)